# gvfs-trash:how can I empty the "Trashcan" when I turn on the computer?

Tags: linux, unix, recycle-bin

For the reason of security,I use ***gvfs-trash*** to delete file or directory.***gvfs-trash***  sends files or directories to the  "Trashcan",I want to empty the "Trashcan"  when I turn on the computer,so I add "gvfs-trash --empty" in the file /etc/rc.local, but it does not work,
how can I do it?

Comment: You can try adding it to `.bashrc`; that might work I guess!.But I don't know if this is a valuable suggestion!

Comment: Your are right,it is a valuable suggestion!